# Append query string on <asp:ScriptReference> Path property value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

Due to prevent client from using browser cached, old JavaScript file, I append a query string to the script file path on my ASP.NET web application, and the query string content is from the server side code. In the plain HTML  element as:

```
<script src="../Scripts/MyScript.js?ver=<%=WebSettings.Version%>"></script>
```

The client output would be:

```
<script src="../Scripts/MyScript.js?ver=20160810"></script>
```

and it works fine. But this approach is not work in the <asp:ScriptReference>. If I using this code:

```
<asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/MyScript.js?ver=<%=WebSettings.Version%>"/>
```

it seems like ASP.NET will treat whole content on value of Path as a string and performs HTML encoding on it, and rendering such output:

```
<script src="../Scripts/MyScript.js?ver=&lt;%=WebSettings.Version%>"></script>
```

Since the <asp:ScriptReference> is child node of the <telerik:RadScriptManager> that I can't just modify them as plain HTML  tag, how can I append dynamic query string on the path of <asp:ScriptReference> to solve the JavaScript file versioning issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried generating the path via server code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = string.Format("~/JavaScript.js?ver={0}", "versionNumber");
    ScriptReference sr = new ScriptReference(path);
    RadScriptManager1.Scripts.Add(sr);
}
```

Or, you can just add the `<script>` tag after the script manager, there will be no difference

```
        <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </telerik:RadScriptManager>
        <script src="../Scripts/MyScript.js?ver=<%=WebSettings.Version%>"></script>
```

Comment: In the second approach, did you mean add <script> after <telerik:RadScriptManager>, not inside it (say, as child node of it)?

Comment: I meant after, like in the second code snippet I added. THe result will, basically, be the same, in the rendered HTML you will get <script> tags for each script entry, so adding yours after the script manager will simply push it a bit down, at worst. But the programmatic creation from the first snippet should work as well.